# Smarty foreach:for every iteration add class

Tags: class, foreach, smarty, addition

I have a foreach loop code in a tpl file like this:

```
[{foreach from=$oView->getArticleList() item=actionproduct name=test_articleList}]
[{include file="inc/product_alt.tpl"  product=$actionproduct testid="action_"|cat:$actionproduct->oxarticles__oxid->value test_Cntr=$smarty.foreach.test_articleList.iteration}]
[{/foreach}]
```

the included file `product_alt.tpl` in the foreach loop contains a simple div container and get displayed for each product. Now i am looking for a solutions to add to every second div container a extra class.

I google a bit and found out (i think so) that I must work with even and odd. But i stucked how to apply this exactly to the foreach loop with the goal that every secod div container get an extra class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `cycle`. What you can do for instance is assign an extra `$class` variable in your include statement, that gets changed by the assign, like so:

```
 {cycle values='yourClass1,youClass2' assign='class'}
```

That's probably where your odd/even thought comes from: the manual says

```
 {cycle values='odd,even' assign='class'}
```

But those are just values. Anyeay, your variable 'class' now has alternating "yourClass1" and "yourClass2" (or odd/even) as content. If you assign this to your include, and then add something like

```
<div class="{$class}">
```

You get alternating classes. One of them is the one you want. the other can be empty..

check out the cycle manual: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.cycle

Comment: Thanks man. This sounds very good. I try it next week and give you some feedback.

Comment: I tried it just right now and works great but with one small error. It begin to assign and cycle the classes at the second div and not at the first one. So the first div container did not get any extra class.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that would come to be, The only thing you might want to try for basic debugging is to do this in a small example (without the include for instance), until you got that perfect, and then extrapolate to the include method?